# How do I apply the one handler to different table rows? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I would like to set the html to "" after a key has been pressed (once). This is my code so far:

```
$(document).one("keypress","td",function(){
        $(this).html("");
});
```

However, it only works with one table row. Is there away I can apply this to all my table (which is loaded dynamically) rows?

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="True">Some text</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="True">Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you apply a keypress to a td? That doesn't make any sense. Keypress is for input.

Comment: @Steven yes, however events do bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would switch to .on and just make the td no longer match the selector after it has been clicked once.

```
$(document).on("keypress","td:not(.cleared)",function(){
    $(this).empty()/*.html("")*/.addClass("cleared");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VBHpU/1/

Comment: using the .cleared/addclass is the same as using .one. So what would be the benefit of changing it to on?

Comment: .one only fires once for each selected element, so it will only work on the first keypress because it's bound to the document which is only one element. http://jsfiddle.net/VBHpU/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/VBHpU/1/